# How to export a Firebase Cloud function v2 with a name containing hyphens / dashes (kebab-case)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is the function (the same `helloWorld` example that you get from `firebase init` functions command).

```
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';

export const helloWorld = onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from Firebase v2!');
});
```

When trying to deploy it, I'm getting the following error:

> Error: helloWorld v2 function name(s) can only contain lower case
> letters, numbers, hyphens, and not exceed 62 characters in length

Given that limitation, I would like to name it as `hello-world`.

But how can I export a `hello-world` variable name in JS?

---

**UPDATE**

I just tried:

```
exports['hello-world'] = onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from Firebase v2!');
});
```

And now I get the error:

> Error: Function name "hello-world" is invalid. Function names cannot
> contain dashes.

What can I name it then?

I don't want to name it `helloworld` (all lowercase).

They accept hyphens but not dashes? That's very confusing.

---

UPDATE 2:

I tried the approach from the answer below, but it does not seem to work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @cbdeveloper when I'm trying to create firebase function with dashes/hyphens I'm obtaining following error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74332294/firebase-functions-v2-changing-dash-to-dot-during-deploy
Did you faced similar issue?

Comment: @BąQ , no. That's a different error than the one I got.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to export your function with dashes. Here's one way of exporting the function:

```
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';

const helloWorld = onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from Firebase v2!');
});

export { helloWorld as "hello-world" }
```

**Note:** If you're using Visual Studio or other IDE, it can be recognized as invalid but deploying it will not be a problem. See sample below:

[image]

You can also check this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for other ways of export declaration.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried your approach but I can't make it work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What error have you encountered when using the code above?

Comment: I've added the errors to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late for this, but for anyone questioning how to do apply kebab case on FB Functions routes, just do this:

```
import { default as world } from '@httpFunctions/helloworld';

exports.hello = {
  world,
};
```

Now, when you try the route `something/hello-world` will be accessible.

Basically, what Firebase does is read the properties from objects on routes and convert them into separated by "-" on urls.