# Firebase Functions V2 changing dash to dot during deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created function V2 as below:

```
exports["processing-file-finished"] = functions.database.onValueWritten(
            {
                instance: this.app.realtimeDatabase,
                ref: "/processing/{fileId}/finished",
            },
            myModule.handleFinish
        )
```

but when I try to deploy this function like:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:processing-file-finished
```

or

```
firebase deploy --only functions:processing.file.finished
```

I'm obtaining following error in cloud console:

```
Function 'processing.file.finished' is not defined in the provided module.
```

Everything works fine in case when I will change name to `processingfilefinished`

Could someone explain me how can I use dashes in function name?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please share what error you get when you use ```firebase deploy --only functions:processing-file-finished```.

Comment: @Vaidehi Jamankar there is no error. I'm obtaining error only after launching. I figure out that I can export it as 
    exports.processing = {
        file: {
            finished: myModule.handleFinish,
        }
    }
Then function will be available under `processing-file-finished`

Comment: Glad to hear, your issue is now resolved, please post the same as an answer here,so other community members who reach here,could be helped in the same scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found solution (or maybe rather some kind of workaround).

Instead of exporting:

```
exports["processing-file-finished"] = functions.database.onValueWritten([...])
```

Im exporting

```
exports.processing = {
    file: {
        finished: functions.database.onValueWritten([...])
    }
}
```

It is according to [Organize Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions)

Thanks to this I'm able to reach my function under `processing-file-finished` but unfortunately I will be not able to expose function under just `processing` segment. That's why this is for me only a workaround.

Cheers!